# After insert id in textbox click enter in textbox fill data in form using ajax php sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I need fill form after insert id in textbox using ajax and php and sql 
I am need show each value in sprate text box currently return all data in one textbox here code ajax

```
function getname()
 {
   var id=$("#id").val();   
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    dataType:"json",
    data:"id="+id,
    url:"page.php",   
    success:function(json)
    { 
        $("#name").val(json);   

    }
    });

  }
```

here is code html

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" tabindex="1" onkeypress="getname()">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

here is code php

```
<?php
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $db_host = 'MOHAMMAD-PC\SQL2005';
  $db_username = 'sa';
  $db_password = '123321';
  $db_name = 'db_test';
  mssql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
  mssql_select_db($db_name); 
  $query=mssql_query("select * from user_info where id='$id'");
  $result=mssql_fetch_assoc($query);

       $json= "{$result['id']}"."{$result['name_ar']}";    
  echo json_encode($json);
exit;

?>
```

Very Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You echo json-encoded concatenated string instead of array.
Change

```
 $json= "{$result['id']}"."{$result['name_ar']}";
```

to

```
 $json= array('id'=>$result['id'], 'name'=>$result['name_ar']);
```

And in ajax function change:

```
success:function(json)
    { 
        $("#name").val(json);   

    }
```

to

```
success:function(json)
    { 

        $("#id").val(json.id);   
        $("#name").val(json.name);   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks n-dru   after edit problem in      success:function(json)
    { 
        var res = JSON.parse(json);
        $("#id").val(res[0]);   
        $("#name").val(res[1]);   
    } not work correctly

Comment: call console.log and see in your console tray what that ajax response is - you will see if it is array and what it contains

Comment: n-dru I am used console.log() not show any think problem its here var res = JSON.parse(json);